# Android, Json and volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have this code to put some data into MySQL and works :

```
insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("firstName",nome.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("lastName",cognome.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("age",anni.getText().toString());

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

    });
```

But this code for recive data from MySQL don't work, why?

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("ww");
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                    try {
                        System.out.println("fin qui ci siamo");
                        JSONArray students = response.getJSONArray("students");
                        for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(i);

                            String firstname = student.getString("firstname");
                            String lastname = student.getString("lastname");
                            String age = student.getString("age");

                            result.append(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age + " \n");
                        }
                        result.append("===\n");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.append(error.getMessage());

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    });
```

The PHP code to put data into MySQL is :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showStudent();
}

function showStudent(){
    global $connect;

    $query = " Select * FROM STUDENT; ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array  = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("students"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

*(Also sorry for bad english, I'm italian)*

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting response? If so, can you update your code with logcat and json response.

Comment: when i press the button to get the data : 10-10 18:13:39.437    2085-2085/com.example.ale.network I/System.out﹕ ww

Answer (score 1):

**First**,

Change your SQL Query from

```
$query = " Select * FROM STUDENT; ";
```

to

```
$query = "Select * FROM STUDENT"; (Remove semi-colon inside of double quotes)
```

Are you sure you have table `STUDENT`?

**Second**,

In your key/value pair for first name, you have declared key as `firstName` when putting content

```
parameters.put("firstName",nome.getText().toString());
```

but you tried to access them by `firstname` instead of `firstName`

```
String firstname = student.getString("firstname");
```

Answer (score 0):

//  Change code on MainActivity.java as following

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Method.POST,showUrl,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
```

Comment: Please explain how and why your code works. This makes your answer more helpful to other people with the same problem.